# if condition in ARM Template resource

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a resource in my Arm Template as follows:

```
parameters:

env
prodparam
nonprodparam

resources:

{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
  "url": "[if(equals(parameters('env'),'prod'), parameters('prodparam'), parameters('nonprodparam'))]"
}
```

I see the url is always set to parameters('nonprodparam') even if parameters('env') = 'prod'. Is this if condition correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're deploying it, such as the parameter inputs? Perhaps the `env` parameter you're passing is `Prod`, in which case the comparison is case sensitive and will NOT match `prod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if condition` statement is correct, I tested it and got the correct result successfully.

You need to do the following steps to check where your problem is:

**1.** Check if your parameter definition is correct, especially as `Stringfellow` mentioned in the comment, to be case sensitive. It should be defined as follows.

[image]

**2.** Pay attention to whether to `save` after editing `arm templates` in the azure portal.

[image]

You can check the value of the parameter during the deployment process:

[image]